# Why are some apps like GMusicBrowser and LightLocker in Japanese instead of my computer's Spanish in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, language-support, gmusicbrowser, light-locker

I have a problem with some Xubuntu apps like GMusicBrowser in which they appear all in Japanese and I don't know how to fix it to show them up in native Spanish. Could somebody help me in that?

Comment: Can you please edit your question by adding the output of the `locale` command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess and assume that you had a problem similar to mine, when I installed xubuntu, I selected english but many things appeared in arabic, because I selected Lebanon from the installation wizard.

to fix this settings -> language & support, language for menus and windows spanish -> apply system wide

regional formats spanish -> apply